# Как отловить событие разрешения и запрета записи getUserMedia?

Tags: javascript, html5

Функцию, определяющию момент когда юзер дает добро на запись можно поместить в gotStream (см. файл main.js по ссылки). Но пользователь может взять, да отклонить свое подтверждение на разрешение записи и этим все поломать. Как отловить этот момент?

http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html

http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/js/main.js

Таймер использовать не хочу, ибо это нагрузочно, да и пока он успеет сработать кто знает что произойдет со скриптом во время записи (когда доступ резко прекращается)

Comment: А `errorCallback` в этот момент не вызывается?

Comment: Нет, не вызывается, функция продолжает записывать пустоту

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1**: Использовать ssl - это предотвращает повторный запрос на запись.

> If your app is running from SSL (https://), this permission will be
>   persistent. That is, users won't have to grant/deny access every time.
>   [Информация](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/).

**Вариант 2:** отлавливать error.

Имеем функцию:
`navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successCallback, errorCallback);`
следовательно:

```
navigator.getUserMedia (
   // constraints
   {
      video: true,
      audio: true
   },
   // successCallback
   function(localMediaStream) {
      var video = document.querySelector('video');
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
      video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
         // Do something with the video here.
      };
   },

   // errorCallback
   function(err) {
    if(err === PERMISSION_DENIED) {
      // Explain why you need permission and how to update the permission setting
    }
   }
);
```

**Вариант 3:** использовать Вариант 1 + Вариант 2

P.S.: Подобный вопрос уже рассматривался [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993581/reprompt-for-permissions-with-getusermedia-after-initial-denial).

Comment: Да, но когда пользователь сначала открывает доступ, а потом берет и закрывает его - функции повторно не вызываются

Comment: Вот http://tau.rghost.ru/7ppDmpkfB/image.png

Comment: Но не везде так, в мозиле он делает это на лету

Comment: Да, я уже столкнулся с этим когда начал решать задачу конвертирования в mp3, никто даже не может помочь с преобразование приходящего массива в blob

Comment: Это как раз то, чего бы я хотел избежать

Comment: @Fangog а выбора то больше нет, разумеется это более напряжно, но в ином случае остается только ждать развития функционала.